# Could cd-r unused space on completed (finalized) disc be utilized?

Tags: compact-disc

The r writable layer is permanently distorted during the write stage and it can never be re-written, but what about the unused area?

I see the data from the outermost edge of the disc toward the center but I don't see any alteration in the remaining space. It looks as if that area might be able to be written to if the 'completed' notice could be ignored or bypassed.

Comment: Unused space in a finalized CD-R cannot be used. Not finalized it can, depending on the software supporting multi-session.

Comment: Short answer: No.